# Null value when passing AJAX parameter to ASP.net Controller, and AJAX calls GET instead of POST controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to pass a simple string value using AJAX to my controller. AJAX reaches the controller but gives it a null value. Also if I add  verb to my controller it gives me error.

Controller:

```
 Public Function SaveSelectedAnswer(ByVal strAnswer As String) As ActionResult

        Return Content(" OK ")

 End Function
```

Script:

```
var rad = document.frmQuestion.SelectedAnswer;

for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function() {
        SendToController(this.value);
    };
}

function SendToController(answer) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Students/SaveSelectedAnswer",
        type: "GET",
        data: answer,
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("From Controller:" + data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: `console.log(answer)` inside `SendToController` before `ajax` and see what value you are getting?

Comment: It needs to be `data: { strAnswer: answer }`,

Comment: @Suprabhat, OP is returning text - `Return Content(" OK ")` so it does need to be `dataType: "text"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks it worked :)  However why I must use JSON notation for data if I specified it as plain text.

Comment: Its not JSON (although if you used `JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: 'json'` it would be). You need to send back a name/value pair - i.e. `strAnswer: someValue` (as for all form values) otherwise nothing can be matched up. In your case the 'name' part must be `strAnswer` to match the name of the method parameter

Comment: The other problem is that when I change to type: "POST" and add HttpPost verb to controller it gives me "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you sure the name of the method you calling matches the url?

Comment: I have used the same code, just changing it to POST on jQuery and controller, and Firebug gives me GET error!